# How to format string of JSON data obtained from Object.values in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to create a React accordion drop down menu that should display a list of entries that are grouped by each individual ID in the array. Each ID contains a list of thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId which can have multiple entries that consist of id, property, previousValue, and updatedValue The JSON data looks like this

```
[{
   "id": "id1234",
   "thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId": [{
       "id": "id1234",
       "property": "propertyValue",
       "previousValue": "123",
       "updatedValue": "456"
     },
     {
       "id": "id1234",
       "property": "propertyValue2",
       "previousValue": "000",
       "updatedValue": "001"
     },
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": "id456",
   "thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId": [{
       "id": "id456",
       "property": "name",
       "previousValue": "Anakin Skywalker",
       "updatedValue": "Darth Vader"
     },
     {
       "id": "id456",
       "property": "lightsaberColor",
       "previousValue": "blue",
       "updatedValue": "red"
     }
   ]
 },
```

I used `Object.values(data).map` and was able to get a large string of thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId: id, property, previousValue, and updatedValue displaying in the drop down of each ID. The problem is that its just a string that is not grouped by individual entries. I would like to group each item in thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId so that when the dropdown is clicked, they are organized in groups of 4 rather than a large string. I have tried mapping over the keys of the JSON data and logging the result like so:

```js
const keys = Object.keys(data);
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[keys[i]]);
}
```

This gives me each item in the JSON object indexed by the keys. Which is almost what I want. I now need each item of the child array thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId grouped by the index so that I can make it a readable format. Something like:

```
Entries for id1234:

1. id: id1234
   property: property
   previousValue: previousValue
   updatedValue: updatedValue

2. id: id1234
   property: property2
   previousValue: previousValue2
   updatedValue: updatedValue2

3. id: id1234
   property: property3
   previousValue: previousValue3
   updatedValue: updatedValue3
```

I can make it look nice once I have the data formatted correctly. I have also tried mapping over the values of data in the same manner but it throws error "each child should have a unique key prop". Which I thought they did as each child in the array is a key value pair. I think I am on the right track but I have been stuck for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: please provide an example of the result you need for better understanding

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I edited with the expected result, I don't know how to make get rid of whitespace on SO but ideally it would be each entry in the list indexed with numbers and showing the details for that index. Not sure if that is more clear.

Comment: As @rupii mentioned, can you post the format of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you

```
const data = [{
    "id": "id1234",
    "thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId": [{
        "id": "id1234",
        "property": "propertyValue",
        "previousValue": "123",
        "updatedValue": "456"
      },
      //...
    ]
  },
  //...
];
let formattedData = [];

data.forEach(obj => {
    /*
        obj is:
        {
            "id": "id1234",
            "thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId": [{
                "id": "id1234",
                "property": "propertyValue",
                "previousValue": "123",
                "updatedValue": "456"
            },
            //...
            ]
        }
    */
    obj.thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId.forEach(thing => {
        /*
            thing is:
            {
                "id": "id1234",
                "property": "propertyValue",
                "previousValue": "123",
                "updatedValue": "456"
            }
        */
        formattedData.push({
            id: obj.id,
            property: thing.property,
            previousValue: thing.previousValue,
            updatedValue: thing.updatedValue,
        });
    });
});

//use formattedData
```

Comment: I am able to get this to work but for whatever reason it is not tying the entries to the ID. So when I hit the drop down/button it renders the entire list for every item. Can you think of a way to get it to render by the ID? I have tried setting the keys and indexing by key but I can't get it to work because some keys are duplicated when theres multiple IDs for an entry.